# Error 404 the origin server did not find a current representation

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, eclipse-neon, tomcat9

I am trying a basic spring mvc demo and when I run it on tomcat it hits a 404 error saying the servlet does not exists. My code is as follows:

```
web.xml
<!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-mvc-demo-servlet

```
<!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

<!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Home Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String ShowMyPage()
{
    return "main-menu";
}

}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There was a time where I might have remembered enough about our old setup to see what you're missing.  I assume there's one bit of config missing.  The reason I say "old setup" is that we use Spring Boot now.  It completely hides the details in your first two files.  You pretty much just a) generate a project with `https://start.spring.io/`, b) add a controller much like you show, c) run Maven to build a jar file, and d) run the jar file like any Java app.  This is the wonder of Spring Boot.  It's almost too easy.  If you have the choice to start over with Spring Boot, I'd recommend that.

Comment: ...if you can do this, there are numerous tutorials on getting your first request mapping working lickety split. - start here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot

Comment: @SteveThanks a lot for your suggestion. Just starting to learn and got this tutorial where they had this method.

Comment: Ah, good.  I was guessing that. Let me Change Your Life, LOL :)

Comment: You've stood up your own, separate Tomcat instance, right?

Comment: @Steve I have added tomcat server to eclipse

Comment: Ah.  A great thing about Spring Boot is that you never see Tomcat.  It's run for you embedded in your Java application.  You can still configure Tomcat for your specific needs if you need to, but normally, you can just forget its even there.  When you go to production, you don't need to manage a Tomcat installation.  You don't need to drop your .war file in the right place.  Your app is just a single file Java app.  It's so much simpler and cool.  I can't say there are no advantages to the "old way".  I don't know of any.  Maybe that would be a good S.O. question.

Comment: I use IntelliJ, but I think Eclipse has this too.  Check to see if you have a Spring Boot plugin or can add it.  Once you do, you should be able to say "New..Spring Boot Project", answer a few questions, and you'll have a running Tomcat-based app with no work.

Comment: @Steve Ok Thank you will try.

Answer (score 0):

Try matching your example  with my below working solution

web.xml at path spring-tutorial-mvc\WebContent\WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>spring-tutorial-mvc</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context. 
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener. -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-ctx.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!--
        - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The app-ctx.xml as below ,path : spring-tutorial-mvc\WebContent\WEB-INF

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">
   <context:component-scan`enter code here` base-package="com.spring.tutorial" />
</beans>
```

mvc-config.xml at path spring-tutorial-mvc\WebContent\WEB-INF

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.tutorial"/>  
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- 2. HandlerMapping : Used default handler mapping internally -->

    <!-- 3. ViewResolver -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

UserController.java at path spring-tutorial-mvc\src\com\spring\tutorial\controller

```
package com.spring.tutorial.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.giggal.spring.domain.User;
import com.giggal.spring.service.UserService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService; // Service which will do all data
                                // retrieval/manipulation work

    // -------------------Retrieve All
    // Users--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllUsers/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listAllUsers() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/user_list");
        List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
        mav.addObject("users", users);
        return mav;
    }

    // -------------------Retrieve Single
    // User--------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching User with id " + id);
        User user = userService.findById(id);
        return user;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView createUserForm() {
        System.out.println("Inside add...");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/user_form");
        User user = new User();
        mav.addObject("command", user);
        mav.addObject("action", "Add Record");
        return mav;
    }

    // //-------------------Create a
    // User--------------------------------------------------------
    //
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createUser(@ModelAttribute("command") User user, HttpSession session) {
        System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getName());
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("user/master/user_form");
        try {
            if (userService.isUserExist(user)) {
                System.out.println("A User with name " + user.getName() + " already exist");
                // return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
            }

            if (user.getId() == null) {
                userService.saveUser(user);
                mav.setViewName("redirect:../add/?successMsg=Add successfully");
            } else {
                User currentUser = userService.findById(user.getId());
                currentUser.setName(user.getName());
                currentUser.setAge(user.getAge());
                currentUser.setSalary(user.getSalary());
                userService.updateUser(currentUser);
                mav.setViewName("redirect:../add/?successMsg=Update successfully");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            mav.addObject("command", user);
            mav.addObject("errorMsg", "Failed to add / update record");
        }
        return mav;

    }

    // ------------------- Delete a User
    // --------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting User with id " + id);
        User user = userService.findById(id);

        userService.deleteUserById(id);
    }

    // ------------------- Delete All User
    // --------------------------------------------------------

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteAllUsers() {
        System.out.println("Deleting All Users");
        userService.deleteAllUsers();

    }

}
```

Here the url will be e.g.  http://localhost://user/getAllUsers
port : port of your server
context-root is context path of your web application